# ошибка прокси в python requests

Tags: python, requests, proxy

Первый вариант, все по гайду

```
import requests
gg = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/ip', proxies={'https':'86.34.197.6:23500'})
print(gg.text)
```

Ошибка

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Proxy URL had no scheme, should start with http:// or https://
```

Второй вариант

```
import requests
gg = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/ip', proxies={'https':'https://86.34.197.6:23500'})
print(gg.text)
```

Ошибка

```
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ip (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000022F0975E3A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера')))
```

помогите исправить ошибку

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `proxies={'https':'86.34.197.6:23500'}`.

Comment: михаил, первый вариант

Comment: Второй вариант видимо правильный, просто сама прокси недоступна.

Comment: Crazyelf, попробовал еще 3 разных прокси с 3 разных сайтов, не помогает